# What is the most adavanced net in applications in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Keras provides serveral pretrained models, like mentioned here:

https://keras.io/applications/

These applications are pretrained networks, like the following:

- Xception
- VGG16
- VGG19
- ResNet50
- InceptionV3
- MobileNet

I know that, VGG16 and VGG19 are fairly old networks in comparison to the others. However, is there a simply way to find out which model is the strongest or has the most weights?

One can look at the amount of layers by simpyly executing sth like:

```
model = applications.ResNet50(...)
print(len(model))
```

However, this does not give any information about the amount of weights provided, or the complexity (e.g. ResNet is residual, while VGG19 is not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These models are implemented based on the corresponding original papers, which you can also see in the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/applications/).

For the detailed pros/cons of each model, you should read the papers. The newer model is not always the better in all applications.

For model size, you can see the number of weights in each layer by:

```
[w.size for w in model.get_weights()]
```